# Instalar pgadmin 4 win 2008 R2

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Se que la pregunta no es especifica de programación, pero de pronto alguien me puede ayudar:

Instale el pgadmin 4 versión 2.0 en un servidor con Windows 2008 R2, no genero ningún warning durante el proceso, pero al lanzar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Googleando un poco el código de error no encontré nada relacionado con el pgadmin pero si con el paquete redistribuible de Visual C++, en el servidor quedo instalada la versión de 32 y 64 bits, ¿podrá ser esa la causa?

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho batallar encontré la respuesta:

Al instalar pgadmin este automáticamente instala el paquete redistribuible de Visual C++ 2013, pero para que se ejecute la aplicación también es necesario el paquete redistribuible de Visual C++ 2008 el cual no se instala, lo descargue del sitio de Microsoft y ya se ejecuta la aplicación.